# Making the popup toolbar menus on Windows XP's taskbar stay put during editing

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

I'm looking for a way to make the popup toolbar menus on Windows XP's taskbar stay in place while you edit it, and only close when you tell it to--by clicking outside it, for example.  Right now it disappears after each editing action--such as renaming a file or changing its position on the menu, and you have to click the >> again to pop the menu back up to do more editing.  Any suggestions on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

NT

Answer (score 0):

This is not a issue ! You can't find a way to solve this problem. You can try switching on the "Stay on the top of all windows" option if available